# Detecting Planes through Point Cloud

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Having a point cloud say (10000 points) which are randomly dispersed in 3D unit cube, the question is **how to find planes within the cube** that include more points with an acceptable tolerance (user choice say, 0.1 where the boundaries of the cube of point cloud are ([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])?
I thought since it is a geometry problem would be asked here, however your comments are more than welcome!

Comment: @PeterSheldrick Thanks for the comment. The first approach is of my interest for which the absolute euclidean distance is being measured. Furthermore I should add that it is desired that all points finally being associated with a plane even in the worst case where there were only three points for planes satisfying the condition of tolerance.

Comment: A good starting point is the Hough transform, which is often used in computer vision applications.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: This is my second time I'm being recommended to consider RANSAC. The first was on my other [post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/517/point-pattern-recognition). Your simple description above could help me to solve another problem even being not fully followed RANSAC stages. If you believe RANSAC could be one of the best solution could I ask you give the community a gift by answering the question in details? Mathematical background and some pseudo-code also could be helpful.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick, Thanks for a series of keywords. Indeed, I had already used similar method for the problem with success without knowing RANSAC. The idea behind the question is however to explore a variety of methods with different background in mathematics or implementation.